# Loop JSON Data on PHP menu

Tags: php, arrays, json, if-statement, foreach

I want to display our dispensary menu in categorical order. The code provided on the site was this:

```
<?php
            $menuItems = $client->menuItems();
            $menuItems = json_decode($menuItems, true);

            foreach($menuItems['menu_items'] as $item)
            {
               print($item['name']);
            }
            ?>
```

but it displays all our menu. I only want to display the menu that belongs to 'cannabis' category. Below is the json data:

```js
{
  "menu_items": [
    {
      "on_hold":false,
      "price": {
        "ounce": 250.0,
        "quarter": 0.0,
        "eighth": 50.0,
        "gram": 20.0,
        "half": 0.0
      },
      "category": "Cannabis",
      "measurement": "grams",
      "sativa":0,
      "thc_percent":0,
      "cbn":0,
      "updated_at":"2010-12-22T23:29:02-07:00",
      "amount":3.0,
      "cbd":0,
      "genetics":"",
      "body_html":"",
      "created_at":"2010-08-09T15:58:08-07:00",
      "name":"Kush",
      "indica":0,
      "id":3654,
      "picture": {
        "original":"https://mmjmenu.com/images/attachments_missing/menu_items/images/missing_original.png",
        "square":"https://mmjmenu.com/images/attachments_missing/menu_items/images/missing_square.png",
        "large":"https://mmjmenu.com/images/attachments_missing/menu_items/images/missing_large.png",
        "small":"https://mmjmenu.com/images/attachments_missing/menu_items/images/missing_small.png",
        "medium":"https://mmjmenu.com/images/attachments_missing/menu_items/images/missing_medium.png"
      }
    },
    {
      "on_hold":false,
      "price": {
        "ounce": 280.0,
        "quarter": 0.0,
        "eighth": 55.0,
        "gram": 25.0,
        "half": 0.0
      },
      "category": "Cannabis",
      "measurement": "grams",
      "sativa":0,
      "thc_percent":0,
      "cbn":0,
      "updated_at":"2010-12-22T23:29:02-07:00",
      "amount":3.0,
      "cbd":0,
      "genetics":"",
      "body_html":"",
      "created_at":"2010-08-09T15:58:08-07:00",
      "name":"Blueberry",
      "indica":0,
      "id":3654,
      "picture": {
        "original":"https://mmjmenu.com/images/attachments_missing/menu_items/images/missing_original.png",
        "square":"https://mmjmenu.com/images/attachments_missing/menu_items/images/missing_square.png",
        "large":"https://mmjmenu.com/images/attachments_missing/menu_items/images/missing_large.png",
        "small":"https://mmjmenu.com/images/attachments_missing/menu_items/images/missing_small.png",
        "medium":"https://mmjmenu.com/images/attachments_missing/menu_items/images/missing_medium.png"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

i'm using this wrapper https://github.com/nitsujw/mmjmenu-php-client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple if would suffice.

```
<?php
        $menuItems = $client->menuItems();
        $menuItems = json_decode($menuItems, true);

        foreach($menuItems['menu_items'] as $item)
        {
           if( $item['category'] == 'Cannabis') {
               print($item['name']);
           }
        }
?>
```

Comment: spot on, i just have to copy and paste. tnx

Answer (score -1):

Use a simple condition check

```
$menuItems = $client->menuItems();
$menuItems = json_decode($menuItems, true);

foreach($menuItems['menu_items'] as $item)
{
    if ($item['name'] == 'Cannabis')
    {
        print($item['name']);
    }
}
```